# What is the best practice to change on-chain storage from asynchronous task?

Tags: pallet, runtime, storage

I want to change some of the `on_chain` data after running some asynchronous task running in `task_manager`. What is the best way to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only interact with the runtime/on-chain state by sending a transaction. This transaction can then change the on chain data.